# Форма + JSON

Tags: json, php

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема по созданию формы своего рода подбора туров/поездок и .д. с

```
<select>
<option value="CityID">cityName1</option>
<option value="CityID">cityName2</option>
<option value="CityID">cityName3</option>
</select>
```

Что-то вроде этого
Имеется "база" выгружаемая через `JSON`

[Через JSON выгружаются города/страны](http://search.tez-tour.com/toursearch/byCountry?countryId=5732&locale=ru&xml=false)

Как это реализовать,честно, без малейшего понятия :(
Т.к. никогда с json'ом не сталкивался.

Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 1):

Загружаете через `php`:

`ajax.php`

```
echo file_get_contents('http://search.tez-tour.com/toursearch/byCountry?countryId=1');
```

Для клиента я писал статью о динамических списках:
[JavaScript динамические списки](http://lampacore.ru/2012/05/06/javascript-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/)

Пробуйте!)